# How to tie asset to network participant in fabric chaincode

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, public-key-encryption, hyperledger

I am writing chaincode for Hyperledger Fabric using node. I am trying to model a network in which I have a buyer and a seller in a channel whose purpose is exchanging a Car asset.

I do have a transaction which is called *sellCar* and invoked by the seller and it should save as attributes in the world state who is the seller and who is the buyer. I do also have a transaction carReceived which is to be called by the buyer to confirm he has received the car.

I am struggling to determine how to link the car.buyer field of my Car asset to a **valid** identity in the fabric network? In that way I can make sure only the intended buyer can invoke the *carReceived* transaction for his car.

Should I save a copy of the buyer and seller eCerts as part of the transaction? Is this an insecure practice? For example inside the chaincode then check whether the participant invoking *carReceived* matches the car.buyer eCert (which was given in advance to the seller to add in the *sellCar* transaction)

I am unsure how to proceed. I am using Fabric CA as MSP.

Thank you very much in advanced for your help